# Magento 2.2.2 How to implement EAV database structure

Tags: database, eav, magento2.2.2

Up till now i had been working in (**Simple)flat database structure** in my **custom modules**, but now i have to use **EAV database structure** but i don't have any idea, how to implement **EAV structure**.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**EAV** is entity attribute value database model, where data is fully in normalized form. Each column data value is stored in their respective data type table.

**EAV** is complex as it joins 5-6 tables even if you want to get just one product’s details.

Example, for a product
Columns are called attributes in EAV.

- product ID is stored in catalog_product_entity_int table
- product name in catalog_product_entity_varchar  table,
- product price in catalog_product_entity_decimal  table,
- product created date in catalog_product_entity_datetime  table,
- product description in catalog_product_entity_texttable.